# View only your own comments, no one else's?

Tags: 9, comments

I have a client who would like users to be able to comment on content without being able to see any other users' comments. This is for a review system where users shouldn't feel influenced by the views of other users. I'm using Drupal 9.3.14 and a subtheme of [Radix](https://www.drupal.org/project/radix).

I have tried adding this to my theme's comment.html.twig:

```
{% if author_id == user.id %}
    {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

That works for a while, but after a while, users report that they can see *some* other users' comments, but not all of them.

How can I make sure that users can always see only their own comments and no one else's?

Comment: Because you didn't implement any user based caching on that piece of content.

Comment: Thanks, @leymannx. I've been looking into implementing user-based caching, but I have not been able to find any practical advice or examples for doing that. Any pointers? Is there a hook I can implement to deal with caching on comments?

Answer (score 1):

Finding `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access`/`hook_comment_access` not working when trying to return `AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerUser()` after comparing the comment owner ID and current user ID (probably related: [#2879087](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2879087)), can you please try the following preprocess logic? As I currently have no project to properly check this out myself I'm not sure if it works that way and if `#plain_text` can simply be (mis-)used as a cache busting switch in a template at all.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $variables['own_comment'] = [
    '#plain_text' => 'no',
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => ['user'],
    ],
  ];
  /** @var \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment $comment */
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  if ($comment->getOwner()->id() === \Drupal::currentUser()->id()) {
    $variables['own_comment']['#plain_text'] = 'yes';
  }
}
```

```
{% if own_comment['#plain_text'] == 'yes' %}
  {{ content }}
{% else %}
  {{ 'Not your comment'|t }}
{% endif %}
```

Maybe I'm actually doing the same you did and in the end the only way is to implement your own comments field formatter, similar to the one in the [Manage comments on own content](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/manage_comment_own_content) module.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for putting so much effort into that, @leymannx! Unfortunately, it appears that the variable "own_comment" is not being set, so the twig logic you included always goes to "Not your comment." I think you might be right about needing to implement my own comments field formatter. I'm going to look at the module you linked to and see what I can do.

Comment: Metadata attached to a render element bubbles up only if rendered. If you don't have anything to render there is an alternative. Preprocess hooks have a hidden feature that you can add cache metadata to the top level: `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';`. The theme layer bubbles this up, independently from other rendered content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no code with this, just an idea to try. Focus on writing a new permission with a custom module, not modifying the html that is cached. If you hook into Drupal's permissions, then the cache may not be an issue anymore. Plus, this feels more like a permission issue than html issue.

If you install drupal/console, you can run a command lines like
`drupal generate:module` to stub out the initial module then `drupal generate:permissions` to addon to that module a permission. Quick way to stub out a custom module and then put similar php logic you already have in your head, but just add it to drupal a different way.